# regex to capture number in text

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the number in text with a pattern like this:

```
About 181,000 results
```

if I separate these by space, I will get an error when I try to convert the number to integer by `int('181,000')`. How can I capture this number correctly and convert it to an integer?

Comment: Why don't you replace all non-numeric characters with nothing: [`str.replace(r"\D+", "")`](https://regex101.com/r/R1mp0Q/1)

Comment: add `'181,000'.replace(',','')`

Comment: @ctwheels: Better use `locale.atoi()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a regex, you could achieve a `O(n)` solution:

```
>>> s = "About 181,000 results"
>>> int(''.join(i for i in s if i.isdigit()))
181000
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the often overlooked `locale` module with `atoi()`:

```
import re, locale
from locale import atoi

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')

string = "About 181,000 results"

rx = re.compile(r'\b\d+(?:,\d+)*\b')

numbers = [atoi(m.group(0)) for m in rx.finditer(string)]
print(numbers)
```

Which yields

```
[181000]
```